# accessing custom method in model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Im practicing laravel and im making a custom method for my user

In my user model i have build a function like this

```
public function employee(){
    return $this->where('user_type','employee');
}
```

and then in my controller I'm accessing the function like this

```
public function index(){
     $users = User::latest()->employee();
     return UserResource::collection($users);
}
```

but it return an error Method `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::employee does not exist.`how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [local scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#local-scopes) instand

```
public function scopeEmployee($query)
{
   return $query->where('user_type', 'employee');

}
```

Your controller can be as it was !

```
    public function index(){
     $users = User::latest()->employee()->get();
     return ProductsResource::collection($users);
}
```

Comment: error Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::mapInto does not exist.

Comment: maybe the user model is not extending the Model class?

Comment: Please, check it and let me know about it or may be, You forgot just to call `Model::get()`...

Comment: ProductsResource::collection() need a collection as argument, it may be the reason of this error. Try to use the code I edited above

Comment: sir what if i use findOrFail like this  $$user = User::findOrFail($id)->employee()->get(); is it possible?

Comment: No ! employee is called throught Class not Model. Calling of `findOrFail` return instance of Model —User— but your model doesn't have `employee` method anymore.

Comment: because sir im planning to get the id and find where the user type = employee

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176754/discussion-between-goms-and-beginner).